# Configure Windows Update group policy in the registry in Windows 10.2004

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, group-policy

In previous versions of Windows 10 Pro, I could configure the Windows Update through group policies and also their corresponding registry values. [Here's the entry description.](https://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/#2791)

With Windows 10.2004, this doesn't match anymore. While the Windows Update (ask before installation) seemed to be applied from the registry key, the restart setting (no automatic restart) did not. Also, none of them were displayed in the group policy editor, everything was displayed as "unconfigured".

When I did configure these settings in the GP editor, the expected registry keys showed up. But they seem to be ignored then. After deleting those values and restarting the computer, the policy was still displayed as "configured" in the GP editor.

I have the impression that Windows 10.2004 broke something there. Registry values and group policy settings no longer match or synchronise.

What is the official method to install group policies automatically (with a single installable file, like .reg) in Windows 10.2004?

I'm especially interested in the settings for

- automatic updates: download automatically but ask before installation
- restart: never restart the computer automatically

Background: The installation of updates easily interferes with foreground realtime activities like video calls or screen recordings. And the computer is secured with BitLocker and requires a PIN to boot. Unattended restarts leave the computer turned off and unusable until I'm back in the office.

Comment: Group policy sets registry settings at login (or system start) and every two hours after that. Most group policy, if not configured to allow or deny, doesn't touch the registry settings. So to be clear - changing registry settings in not doing group policy.

Comment: Then what is? I want a method to make those settings on new computers without going through long lists of settings manually. And I don't have a Windows Server or Windows domain.

Comment: Group Policy Editor is available in all editions but home.

Comment: There is a local group policy for local users. Plus a machine group policy for everyone.

Comment: That's all nice but interactive and a lot of fiddling around with long lists. I need a non-interactive method to change those settings. Something like a .reg file or .msi or whatever.

Comment: There are several valid and supported methods of configuring OS settings and these are very well published and documented. What have you tried? What research have you done?

Comment: @music2myear I have searched the web for automated installation of group policies and similar wordings. Found nothing. Everyone opens the GP editor and does it manually. I know you can do it through a Windows Server domain, too, which I don't have. So what are those "several" methods you're referring to? How can I find them? It would be helpful to know the required search terms.

Comment: You're not "installing group policies". No one "installs group policies". Group Policy is built-in to the OS and cannot be installed. You apply Group Policies. However, in your specific case you don't want to use Group Policy, so you're just trying to automate setting or configuring Windows, and there are several robust and mature ways to do this built in to Windows, including but not limited to Group Policies.

Comment: @music2myear Thank you for your unhelpful comment. I'm not a Windows Server admin. I just want to configure Windows Updates behaviour. gpedit.msc is the only interface I have. It used to work with the registry, too, but no more in Windows 10.2004. I'd be happy about a solution, not corrections to my wording.

Comment: Usually incorrect wording makes it difficult to understand what is asked. In this case it is preventing you from knowing what your own problem actually is and how the system you are working with may have already fixed things. Have you looked in to active hours? I would not be surprised if Windows no longer supports what you've been focused on implementing as they have made great effort to keep sustenance updated, and what you're looking for are ways not to update.

Comment: It seems like this could be useful for me: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Read-or-modify-Registrypol-778fed6e The file is stored in C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Registry.pol